# Does python cache items in the same line and use again later

Tags: python, tuples, interpreter, pythoninterpreter

With this line:

```py
print(sum(tuple), len(tuple), sum(tuple)/len(tuple))
```

Will python cache `sum(tuple)` in the 0 index and use it in the average calculation (2 index)?

Or will with calculate `sum(tuple)` again?

Comment: No, no it will not, since it isn't possible to do that in general safely. The expression `sum(tuple)` is calculated multiple times.

Comment: Note, Python is not a functional programming language, it's functions can have side-effects, so this optimization isn't really possible in principle due to the inherent language semantics. Now, maybe Python *could* special case built-ins, e.g., it knows that `sum` doesn't have a side effect, and it knows that `tuple.__iter__` doesn't have a side effect, but Python can't really know this at runtime

Comment: You can use `:=` operator to not compute sum multiple times, e.g. `print(s := sum(tpl), len(tpl), s / len(tpl))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python won't perform this optimization for you. You can see this by defining your own function instead of `sum` and observing the side effect:

```py
import functools

def my_sum(x):
    print('my sum')
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, x)

tup = (1, 2, 3)
print(my_sum(tup), len(tup), my_sum(tup)/len(tup))
```

If you run this snippet, you'll see the phrase "my sum" printed twice, proving the call to `my_sum` isn't optimized out.

Having said that, you could implement this optimization yourself by using `functools`' [`cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html):

```py
import functools

@functools.cache
def my_sum(x):
    print('my sum')
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b, x)

tup = (1, 2, 3)
print(my_sum(tup), len(tup), my_sum(tup)/len(tup))
```

(or by using the `:=` operator as Andrej Kesely suggests in the comments)

Comment: Note that this only proves that an arbitrary user-defined function bound to `sum` isn't cached; it does not preclude a Python implementation from performing an expression-specific optimization on a built-in that's known to be side-effect-free.

Comment: @chepner I understood the question as the general statement in the title - "Does python cache items in the same line and use again later", where `sum` is just an example. The answer to that question is that in the general case, Python does not cache function results, as I demonstrated in my answer, and you shouldn't assume that it does, at least not without some prior knowledge about a specific function. I agree, however, that my answer did not address whether or not the built-in `sum` function was optimized in this way or not.

Comment: Does the ```:=``` operator make the code go slower? Or is it faster?

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesnt cache the results as other answers already pointed out.

However, since Python 3.8 you can use assignment expressions with the so-called walrus operator `:=`.
It 'assigns values to variables as part of a larger expression' and 'helps you avoid calling  twice' as explained [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html).

You can also use the operator multiple times in one statement. In this example I assign the result of sum() to one variable `s`, the result of len() to a second variable `l` and then print `s/l`.

```
your_tuple = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
print(s := sum(your_tuple), l := len(your_tuple), s/l)  # 15 5 3.0
```